# NuxtJS Axios Proxy self signed cert in chain error

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I am getting the following error and I have no idea why.

"[HPM] Error occured while proxying request IPaddress/api/user/group/123456 to https://localhost:8443/ [SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN]"

My nuxt.config.js has

```js
axios: {
  proxy: true, 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
},
proxy:{
  '/api':{
  'target': 'https://localhost:8443',
  'secure': true
},
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tried googling this error? Seems like a broad error but maybe something may help here: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/171

Comment: There isn't anything about the specific self signed cert in chain error in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this had less to do with Nuxt and more to do with Node. I got it solved using this article.

https://medium.com/@jonatascastro12/understanding-self-signed-certificate-in-chain-issues-on-node-js-npm-git-and-other-applications-ad88547e7028